# Как переключиться на класс scss на pug шаблонизаторе(div.header) в phpstorm

Tags: phpstorm, scss, pug

Всем привет. Подскажите, какой плагин скачать или как настроить pug(jade) что бы при работе в phpstorm я мог при клике на класс перейти на этот самый класс, как это доступно с обычным html

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Ответ - никак не настроить, и плагинов таких нет.
Это работает только для синтаксиса вида `div(class="sample")`, но не для `div.sample`.

Проголосуйте, пожалуйста, за [WEB-29449](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-29449), чтобы получать уведомления об изменении статуса этого запроса

Comment: Похоже забили на эту доработку. А зря :(